# 100% minus a textnode

Tags: css, css-float

I've got this simple markup:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="static">
        Hello Random
    </div>
    <div id="max">
        100% of the rest
    </div>
​</div>​
```

I want that the div with ID `max` should be 100% width as its parents minus the width of the element with ID `static`. `static` contains just a single textnode with some random words that I don't know.

I have tried this CSS but don't know exactly how to solve it:

```
#parent{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #FF0000;
    float:left;
}

#static{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #00FF00;
}
#max{
    float:left;
    width:90%; // It's not the same as minus so this will just fail...
}
​
```

This is my jsFiddle that I have tried with:
http://jsfiddle.net/WnceY/

I want to use pure CSS no JS. In this moment I don't care about IE either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/WnceY/9/

Answer (score 0):

Just don't float everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/WnceY/4/

Only the `#static` needs to float. Then the rest will take care of itself.

Comment: Hm, that will not work couse the element with ID max will go behind the other ones, if you deactive all borders you will see it:
http://jsfiddle.net/WnceY/3/

Comment: Is that a problem? Then you'll need to tell me more of your requirements.

Comment: Yes it is, I will update my question couse it was unclear ;-) Inside the element named max I have another element that is X% of its parent. It looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WnceY/7/ the main goal is to create a progressbar width fixed textnode on its left. The textnode could be some randomwords.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't have an answer I'm afraid. Unless you're willing to give the progress bar a fixed width (say, 60%) and allow the static text to use the remaining space. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I found a solution and posted it as an answer